# Can I index a column in parquet file to make it join faster using Spark

Tags: hadoop, join, apache-spark, parquet

I have two DataFrames each saved in a parquet file. I need to join this two DFs by the unique incremental "id" column.
Can I created index on the id column so they can join faster? Here is the code

```
// First DF which contain a few thousands items
val dfExamples = sqlContext.parquetFile("file:///c:/temp/docVectors.parquet")
// Second DF which contains 10 million items
val dfDocVectors = sqlContext.parquetFile(docVectorsParquet) // DataFrame of (id, vector)

dfExamples.join(dfDocVectors, dfExamples("id") === dfDocVectors("id")).select(dfDocVectors("id"),
dfDocVectors("vector"), dfExamples("cat"))
```

I need to perform such kind of join many times. To speed up the join, can I create index on
the "id" column in the parquet file like what I can do to a database table?

Answer (score 3):

Spark joins use an object called a [partitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Partitioner).  If a DataFrame has no partitioner, executing a join will involve these steps:

1. Create a new hash partitioner for the bigger side
2. Shuffle both dataframes against this partitioner
3. Now we've got the same key on the same node, so local join operations can finish the execution

You can optimize your join by addressing some of #1 and #2.  I'd suggest that you repartition your bigger dataset by the join key (id):

```
// First DF which contain a few thousands items
val dfExamples = sqlContext.parquetFile("file:///c:/temp/docVectors.parquet")
// Second DF which contains 10 million items
val dfDocVectors = sqlContext.parquetFile(docVectorsParquet)
  .repartition($"id")
// DataFrame of (id, vector)
```

Now, joining any smaller dataframe with dfDocVectors is going to be much faster -- the expensive shuffle step for the big dataframe has already been done.